# XMLReader is unknown

Tags: c#, xml

Following this [introduction](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmlreader-class/) one can use the XMLReader class by importing the namespace `System.Xml`. In my Visual Studio project I use .NET 4.0, but `System.Xml` is unknown:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

In my code I wrote:

```
using System.Xml;
```

What I am missing?

Comment: When you open your project references folder, System.Xml is in there right?

Comment: "are you missing an assembly reference"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a reference to the `System.Xml` assembly (`System.Xml.dll`). I'm surprised it doesn't exist in the project by default, but you may have removed it.

Note that namespaces and assemblies are different things - a `using` directive only imports the namespace so you can use simple names (e.g. `XmlReader`) without further qualification, but you still need the *assembly* reference as well, in the project settings.

(As an aside, I'd personally avoid using `XmlReader` directly unless you really need to handle huge documents. I'd use LINQ to XML where possible - the `XDocument`, `XElement` classes etc. For those, you'll need a reference to the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly.)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the additional information, too. Now I see why it wasn't referenced by default, because the project was created as Unit Test Project in VS2012.